# Is anyone currently in jail/prison as the result of a private prosecution in the USA?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, prosecution

Private prosecutions are  extremely rare but not completely disappeared in the US, and persist in a few states.  I want to get a sense of just how rare they are.

Is there anyone currently in jail/prison as a result of a private prosecution in one of the states which allow them? If not, when was the last time this occurred.

Comment: "...and persist in a few states." Which states?

Answer (score 4):

New Jersey, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island and Virginia [still allow private prosecutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_prosecution#United_States) that can result in incarceration. See also a state by state summary [here](https://law.lclark.edu/live/files/26911-50-states-victim-initiated-investigation).

A bar on conflicts of interest (e.g. having the same lawyer pursue a private prosecution and a civil case against the same defendant) [greatly limit the practice in Virginia](https://katzjustice.com/private-prosecutors-are-limited-by-virginia-law-says-fairfax-criminal-lawyer/) (see also [here](http://www.courts.state.va.us/opinions/opncavtx/2158963.txt)). [There is an argument](https://scholarlycommons.law.wlu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1444&context=wlucdj) that this limitation has federal constitutional force. But see, *Cantrell v. Commonwealth*, 229 Va. 387 (1985) (analysed [here](https://crimlaw.blogspot.com/2014/02/private-prosecutors.html)).

> Is there anyone currently in jail/prison as a result of a private
> prosecution in one of the states which allow them? If not, when was
> the last time this occurred.

They are very rare, and often limited to misdemeanors. I suspect that there is currently someone in incarcerated on the basis of one, but it isn't easy to determine as there are no one who maintains statistics regarding this. Convictions in private prosecutions have resulted in appellate decisions as recently as 2020 in Virginia.

A private prosecution resulting in a conviction with a one-year suspended sentence and one year of probation was [affirmed on appeal in 2001 in Rhode Island](https://caselaw.findlaw.com/ri-supreme-court/1137719.html).

[In many Rhode Island cases](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/56705952.pdf), this involves prosecutions by police officers (see also [here](https://theappeal.org/rhode-island-police-prosecutors/) noting that this is also common in "New Hampshire, New Mexico, South Carolina, and Virginia, where police officers can act as prosecutors throughout the entire misdemeanor process—from a defendant’s first appearance through a plea or trial").

A (pay per view) [2011 law review article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23058573) reviews the practice of victim prosecutions in New Hampshire (where incarceration may not be sought), New Jersey, and Rhode Island.

Comment: Steven Donziger was put under house arrest for about 1,000 days despite the prosecutor's office specifically declining to prosecute him for any criminal offense. I would argue that was a private prosecution despite the judge purporting to make three attorneys he selected "acting prosecutors" specifically for this action. All this under Federal law. The Supreme Court denited cert and will not hear his appeal.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Donziger deals with criminal and remedial contempt of court prosecutions. This is a conceptually different concept from a private prosecution of a crime unconnected to indirect contempt of court as a satellite proceeding related to another primary case. In a private prosecution it is a direct case and the separation of powers issues raised in Donziger aren't present and more than in a civil action commenced by a private party.

Comment: It's a way for courts to put people in jail even if nobody in the executive branch thinks a crime was committed. There were only two proceedings it was associated with -- one was an ordinary prviate civil lawsuit and the other was the criminal action. The separation of powers issues are precisely the same -- in both cases, you have someone the state punishes with imprisonment without any executive branch checks on whether a criminal prosecution is appropriate.